# Xcode is crashing when launching app with CoreSpotlight (9.0+) on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, corespotlight

I'm working on integrating `CoreSpotlight` framework functionality with the app and try to run it on iOS 8.3 device. Every time I've got:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreSpotlight.framework/CoreSpotlight
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F9714BAD-1386-42A7-9B5F-5C06607AF6CE/Quotes.app/Quotes
Reason: image not found
```

- I have marked `CoreSpotlight` as `Optional`.
- Every target (App + Tests) has set **Link Frameworks Automatically** to **NO** and also main project has this flag set the same.

I don't see where is the problem and why this is still not working.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Stupid question potentially but have you tried a clean before building? Sometimes paths can get messed up, and cleaning can fix that

Comment: @Aggressor, yes I tried.

Comment: Can you post your Build Settings?

Comment: Here is dump from configuration: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11493275/project.pbxproj - There is nothing special except that I added -weak-framework linking according to this document but still not working - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your build phases with the arrows expanded?

Comment: Sure, there you go: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11493275/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-09%20at%2022.53.42.png

Comment: How come your CoreSpotlight framework isnt in there?

Comment: I am importing it in files where I need it: `import CoreSpotlight`. By default it is not added there.

Comment: In your link Binary With Libraries, hit the + button and type in CoreSpotlight and add that then try running

Comment: The same crash with Required or Optional selected.

Comment: What about if you add it to the embeded frameworks section?

Comment: It doesn't work. Running ends with Xcode error: "Could not inspect the application package".

Comment: :( Sorry Im not sure then

Comment: Okay, thanks for help anyway. Will take a look on this issue later and just install 9.0 and this problem will be postponed.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem, but resolved it this way:

1. under "Linked Frameworks and Library", added CoreSpotlight, and
   marked it as Optional
2. Clean build folder (Alt+Shift+Command+K)
3. Build and run on iOS8 device

Works for me (Xcode7 Beta4)